# Is it possible to add the values of two variables using Morphline's inbuilt set of commands?

Tags: morphline

I'm wondering if there is any way to add the values of two variables in morphlines, without having to write a custom command.

For example, something like:

```
addValues {
            answer : "@{value_one}" + 50
          }
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find out how to (or whether it was possible to) do this using Morphline's inbuilt commands. however, it is possible to do so within the java{} command, which allows you to write plain java code in-line in the Morphlines config.